# display unique data from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables. ProductA and ProductB.

ProductA

```
ID SubId

A1 112
A1 113
A1 114
B1 111
C1 113
C1 115
D1 117
D1 118
E1 114
```

ProductB

```
ID SubId

A1 112
A1 118
B1 111
B1 113
C1 114
D1 117
D1 118
E1 115
E1 116
E1 117
```

I want to write a query which outputs two columns ID and SubId and  displays distinct SubId columns for a particular ID. So for the above tables, for column A it will display following:

```
ID SubId

A1 112
A1 113
A1 114
A1 118
```

How can I get this done?

Comment: A1 112 doesn't seem to be "unique".

Comment: @ForgottenSemicolon I meant display distinct. If its present in both the tables then display once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming by saying unique, you really just mean no duplicates as per your example result, You want to use UNION

```
SELECT ID, SubID
FROM tblA
UNION 
SELECT ID, SubID
FROM tblb
```

Comment: Wouldn't there need to be a group by as well?

Comment: @DanielGraham - Only if the records are non-unique in each table individually.  The `UNION` already de-dupes when combining the two data-sets.  *(`UNION ALL` would **not** do the de-dupe.)*

Comment: Ahh yes. I was thinking from the UNION ALL standpoint, but now realize that your example was using the UNION by itself. Good call!